# trace_sched_wakeup is called in the linux kernel, but appears not to be defined anywhere?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how waking up works in the linux kernel, but I noticed here that [ttwu_do_wakeup()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.99/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2305) calls trace_sched_wakeup, but that this function does not appear to be defined in the linux kernel. The elixir browser says that this "identifier is not used," although there is a trace_sched_wakeup.c file.

I also tried grep'ing the kernel on my machine, and I also didn't find any places where the trace_sched_wakeup function was defined.

How does this function call go through?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trace_sched_wakeup()` is defined in [trace/events/sched.h, line 96](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.99/source/include/trace/events/sched.h#L96) through a call to the `DEFINE_EVENT` macro:

```
DEFINE_EVENT(sched_wakeup_template, sched_wakeup,
         TP_PROTO(struct task_struct *p),
         TP_ARGS(p));
```

`DEFINE_EVENT` is defined in [linux/tracepoint.h, line 520](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.99/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L520):

```
#define DEFINE_EVENT(template, name, proto, args)       \
    DECLARE_TRACE(name, PARAMS(proto), PARAMS(args))
```

`DECLARE_TRACE` is defined [at line 395](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.99/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L395):

```
#define DECLARE_TRACE(name, proto, args)                \
    __DECLARE_TRACE(name, PARAMS(proto), PARAMS(args),      \
            cpu_online(raw_smp_processor_id()),     \
            PARAMS(void *__data, proto),            \
            PARAMS(__data, args))
```

Finally, `__DECLARE_TRACE` is defined [at line 231](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.99/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L231):

```
#define __DECLARE_TRACE(name, proto, args, cond, data_proto, data_args) \
    extern struct tracepoint __tracepoint_##name;           \
    static inline void trace_##name(proto)              \
    {                               \
        if (static_key_false(&__tracepoint_##name.key))     \
            __DO_TRACE(&__tracepoint_##name,        \
                TP_PROTO(data_proto),           \
                TP_ARGS(data_args),         \
                TP_CONDITION(cond), 0);         \
        if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_LOCKDEP) && (cond)) {     \
            rcu_read_lock_sched_notrace();          \
            rcu_dereference_sched(__tracepoint_##name.funcs);\
            rcu_read_unlock_sched_notrace();        \
        }                           \
    }                               \
...
```

This actually defines `trace_sched_wakeup()` thus:

```
static inline void trace_sched_wakeup(struct task_struct *p) { ... }
```